# JQuery: Exclude elements from .each() selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to loop through a series of menu items contained within 3 nested `<ul>`s but only retrieve the .HTML() from the 2nd layer of nested `<li>`s, eg:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Ignore</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ignore</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ignore</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Retrive me</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Retrive me</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Retrive me</a>
       <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Ignore</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Ignore</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Ignore</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Normally I would use .not() eg:

```
$.each($("#menu ul li ul li a").not("#menu ul li ul li ul li a"), function() {
  var linktext = $(this).html();
  console.log(linktext);
});
```

But this still returns all .html() from 2nd and 3rd level a tags.

Would anyone know how to amend this at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [child selector *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$("#menu > ul > li > ul > li > a").each(...);
```

Or count the number of ancestor `li's` although that would probably be less performant:

```
$('#menu ul a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parentsUntil('#menu', 'li').length === 2;
}).each(...);
```

Comment: What are you getting when you run the first example with the child selectors?  Because that looks correct to me.  I don't see where `#menu` is in your example, maybe its not a direct parent of the first ul?

Comment: @MeltingDog: Then the structure in your actual code must be different, because it works perfectly fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HWV6M/1/. As Mercurybullet said, maybe the `ul` is not a direct child of `#menu`, but since you didn't post any information about it, I just assumed it is. We can only work with the information you provide.

Comment: Hmm  - its just doesnt seem to work in combination with my each statement...I am looking over it again

Comment: Ah - dont worry, my mistake - missed some code. Your answer is correct